# How to organize an automated changelog in Trac?

Tags: trac

I would like to get an automated changelog from Trac, that will include references to tickets that made some important changes to the architecture/design of the code. My ideal scenario would look like this:

1. According to some ticket I make a change to SVN
2. I add some specific line to the ticket saying that this changeset created an important change to the code/wiki
3. I go to some dedicated Trac page and see a full list of such changes made with the project.

In other words, it's going to be a changelog, which is available for all project participants, and the entire team will be updated about the important changes with source code and wiki.

Can you suggest any Trac plugin for this? Or maybe Trac itself can do it?

ps. Would be excellent to have another "Plans Log", where everybody can post their plans on future changes. Again, inside tickets.

Comment: Do you want the changelog to consist of the important tickets, or the important commits, or both?  Do you expect the ticket text, or the commit text to be in a form that's suitable for cleanly readable changelog?

Comment: At least something of what you listed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the ChangeLogMacro on  TrackHacks: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ChangeLogMacro

Sample:

> [7280] by doki_pen on 12/18/09 20:27:15
>
> Update body reference to output.
>
> Since body isn't defined. Fixes #5538
>
> [7191] by doki_pen on 11/26/09
>   02:18:32
>
> watch user feature
>
> fixes #3546
>
> [7190] by doki_pen on 11/26/09
>   02:18:21
>
> copy changes
>
> trying to make things more intuitive
>   for users

Personally I'm looking for something a little more like the VirtualBox changelog which I can then put into a plain text file. So if anyone knows how to do this I'm interested!
www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

Sample:

> VirtualBox 3.1.2 (released 2009-12-17)
>
> This is a maintenance release. The following items were fixed and/or added:
>
> - VMM: fixed SMP stability regression
>
>   - USB: fixed USB related host crashes on 64 bits Windows hosts (#5237)
>   - Main: wrong default HWVirtExExclusive value for new VMs (bug #5664)
>   - Main: DVD passthrough setting was lost (bug #5681)
>   - VBoxManage: iSCSI disks do not support adding a comment (bug #4460)
>   - VBoxManage: added missing --cpus and --memory options to OVF --import
>
> VirtualBox 3.1.0 (released 2009-11-30)
>
> This version is a major update. The following major new features were added:
>
> ```
> * Teleportation (aka live migration); migrate a live VM session from one host to another (see the manual for more information)
> * ...
> ```

Comment: any improvements found?